# How can I add the time that a message arrives in a tickerplant from a feedhandler in KDB

Tags: kdb

I’m wondering what the best way to add the time that data arrives in a KDB tickerplant from a feedhandler. As the data arrives in list form, would it be correct to just append `.z.z` to the end of the list using the join operator?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the tick library from Kx tick? I think it automatically appends the time that data reaches the tickerplant for you.

https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick.q

On line 38:

```
 if[not -16=type first first x;
  if[d<"d"$a:.z.P;.z.ts[]];
  a:"n"$a;x:$[0>type first x;a,x;(enlist(count first x)#a),x]
  ];
```

Here `x` is the table/list that is being sent to the ticker plant and `a` is the timespan that has been added.

Comment: The vanilla tick library does this yes but if the first column is already a time type then .z.P won’t be appended - I want to add this to compare the time that is sent from the feedhandler to the time it arrives in the TP

Comment: I've had this problem before too. You can't append to the beginning (left) of the table / list, tick always checks that the first column is a timespan and the second is a grouped column (if I remember correctly). I think I got around this by just appending to the end, like you said in the original post.

Comment: Yes so for example, if upd is defined as {[t;x] t insert x}, I could modify this to be upd:{[t;x] x,(.z.z); t insert x} assuming there is an addition column to account for this in the table it’s being sent to

Comment: yes, I think that something like `{[t;x]t insert x,.z.z}` would work

Comment: @jamesmcauley You have to be a little careful - any new schema changes (.e.g new columns added to table schema) would now force you to always move your timestamp column to the end of the schema. You'd want to make sure that's well documented/remembered

Comment: You could still add it to the front, but remove the check for `-16=type first first x` in the incoming data and prepend the `a` anyway. This would assume you've implemented it across all your tables

Comment: Yes I was thinking that if it’s appended to the end then it will always have to be the last column in any schemas defined